# How to redirect pages with same structure but different ID at the end

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect different pages which have same structure, but different ids at the end, for example:

```
/test/test-2/some-fun-stuff_73.html
/test/test-2/some-fun-stuff_75.html
/test/test-2/some-fun-stuff_79.html
```

I'd like them to be redirect to:

```
/test/test-2/another-fun-stuff.html
```

I don’t want to have three lines in my `.htaccess`, and I want to solve this through a common rule with regular expressions.

Could you please help me finding the right expression to use, in order to have just on line redirecting everything in my `.htaccess`?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch ^/test/test-2/some-fun-stuff_[0-9]+\.html$ /test/test-2/another-fun-stuff.html
```

in the htaccess file in your document root.

Or, using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/test-2/some-fun-stuff_[0-9]+\.html$ /test/test-2/another-fun-stuff.html [L,R]
```